# Matching values of a dict with the values of two columns of a dataframe and substituting the value of a third column with the key of the dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Index | Line Item                   |        Insertion Order                    | Creative Type
_________________________________________________________________________________________________
1     | blbl 33 dEs '300x600' Q3    | hello 444                                 | UNKNOWN
2     | QQQ4 Hello trueview Apple   | something 68793274                        | UNKNOWN
3     |   A useless  string         | pre-roll Video <10 tttt 89 CASIO          | UNKNOWN
4     | Something not in dict       | Neither here                              | UNKNOWN
```

And a dictionary like this:

```
 dct = {
'RISING STARS': ['300x600', 'Box 300x600', '300x250', 'Box 300x250', 'Classic Skin', 'Main Banner', 'Half Banner', 'Masthead', 'Push Bar', 'Strip', 'In Image', 'Mix formati display rising'],
'VIDEO': ['trueview', 'Video Banner', 'Video in Picture', 'Videobox', 'Mid-roll Video', 'Pre-roll+Inread', 'Pre-roll Video <10', 'Pre-roll Video =10', 'Pre-roll Video =15', 'Pre-roll Video =20', 'Pre-roll Video =30' ,'Pre-roll Video >30','Inread / Intext / Outstream','Mix formati video','Post-roll Video','Inread XXX (Landscape/Vertical/Square)', 'Pre-roll Video Sponsored Session' ,'Pre-roll Video Viewmax' ,'Pre-roll Video Takeover']}
```

I would like to substitute the value in the column Creative Type of my dataframe: if the values of the column `Line Item` or `Insertion Order` match the values of the dictionary, the corresponding row of the column `Creative Type` should take the name of the key of the dictionary. If there is no match, the corresponding row of the column creative type should receive the value `NaN`.

**The expected output is:**

```
Index | Line Item                   |        Insertion Order                    | Creative Type
_________________________________________________________________________________________________
1     | blbl 33 dEs '300x600' Q3    | hello 444                                 | RISING STARS
2     | QQQ4 Hello trueview Apple   | something 68793274                        | VIDEO
3     |   A useless  string         | pre-roll Video <10 tttt 89 CASIO          | VIDEO
4     | Something not in dict       | Neither here                              | NaN
```

What's the easiest way to do it? (less computationally expensive if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **replacement** dictionary by inverting the key-value pairs of given `dict` i.e for each value in the list map it to its corresponding key, then using [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) replace the strings from the combined columns `Line Item` and `Insertion Order` with its corresponding value from replace-ment dictionary when there is a match, finally [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the strings which can't be replaced:

```
r = {rf'(?i).*?\b{z}\b.*':x for x, y in dct.items() for z in y}
s = df['Line Item'].add(':' + df['Insertion Order'])
df['Creative Type'] = s.replace(r, regex=True).mask(lambda x: x.eq(s))
```

---

```
                   Line Item                   Insertion Order Creative Type
1   blbl 33 dEs '300x600' Q3                         hello 444  RISING STARS
2  QQQ4 Hello trueview Apple                something 68793274         VIDEO
3          A useless  string  pre-roll Video <10 tttt 89 CASIO         VIDEO
4      Something not in dict                      Neither here           NaN
```